# How can I get size of array after innerHTML.split?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I got a string "Testing - My - Example"
And I want to split it with " - ".
like this:

```
variable = innerHTML.split(" - ");
```

how do i get the size of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`variable.length`

Comment: `.size` is not a property of arrays. It is a jQuery method, though but `.length` should suffice..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
variable.length
```